# UITextView returns number instead of text

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

stackoverflow, google and coffee have failed to find the answer, however......

specialViewController.h has...

```
@interface SpecialViewController : UIViewController {
UITextView *messageBody;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextView *messageBody;
```

specialViewController.m has....

```
@implementation SpecialViewController
@synthesize messageBody;
```

plus....

```
-(IBAction)executeSpecial:(id)sender{
[self.messageBody resignFirstResponder];
NSString *message = messageBody.text;    
NSLog(@"returned text is  %@", message);
}
```

shows "returned text is 148082" or some random number dependent on the text entered. I just cannot, for the life of me, find out why the text I am entering is not being shown.

Comment: this may or may not have something to do with it, but `UITextView` is usually (but not always) an `IBOutlet`...  is it connected up to your view controller in your xib file?

Comment: and what happens when you change the `NSLog` to point to `messageBody.text` instead of `message`?  Same number output?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, problems like this are from other part of the code that you may not expect. I noticed that you don't have your UITextView marked as an IBOutlet. Are you adding it programmatically? If so, can you give us the code for that.

Comment: I modified the .h to IBOutlet UITextView *messageBody; and no change. Modified the .m to include     [self.messageBody resignFirstResponder];
    NSString *message = messageBody.text;
    NSLog(@"message %@",message);
    NSLog(@"messageBody.text %@",messageBody.text);

Comment: Error found. Decaf coffee! I repurposed the variable elsewhere. As I cannot answer he question myself for a few hours, I apologise and thanks for the quick support.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Gents, problem was decaf coffee! During the course of my coding, I repurposed the variable and this ultimately conflicted. It turns out that I was getting exactly what I asked for. I always find it strange that my applications never do what I want, only what I tell them to......